# Necesito ayuda con una querie en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

Tengo estas tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sucursal(
    numSucursal int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

y esta:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empleado(
    numEmpleado int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    sueldo bigint NOT NULL,
    fContratacion DATE NOT NULL,
    numSucursal int,
    jefe int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkjefe
    FOREIGN KEY (jefe) REFERENCES empleado(numEmpleado),
    CONSTRAINT fksucursal
    FOREIGN KEY (numSucursal) REFERENCES sucursal(numSucursal)
);
```

Tengo que mostrar el sueldo promedio de cada sucursal, pero no encuentro manera de hacerlo, se como sacar el promedio, pero no como vincular a los empleados a una sucursal exactamente.

Al momento de crear un empleado le asigno el numero de su sucursal al campo `numSucursal` como *fk*, pero lo demás no me resulta.

Ayuda por favor, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que esta te puede valer, pruebala y me dices que la he hecho de cabeza y no la he probado

```
SELECT s.numSucursal, 
        AVG(e.sueldo)
FROM sucursal s
INNER JOIN empleado e ON s.numSucursal=e.numSucursal
GROUP BY s.numSucursal;
```

Comment: Funciona excelente, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @Aprendiz OP? no entiendo que quieres decir... estaba con el movil Fabian necesitaba ayuda y se la resolví

Comment: @Aprendiz ah vale perdon no te habia entendido, ahora explico el funcionamiento